# How to display total and percentage in pie chart using highchart in R?

Tags: r, highcharts

I am trying to prepare a dashboard in R using Rmarkdown. I used below code to display pie chart in the dashboard but how do I display total and percentage

```
hc <- df %>%
  hchart(
    "pie", hcaes(x = name, y = count))
hc
```

My output is just a pie chart with name but no number or percentage.

I want output something like this

[image]

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `tooltip.pointFormat` (or `tooltip.format`,`tooltip.formatter`) and `dataLabels.format` (or `dataLabels.formatter`). In this is case:

```
hc_tooltip(pointFormat= "{series.name}: <br>{point.percentage:.1f} %<br>total: {point.total}"),
```

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/tooltip.pointFormat

```
hc_plotOptions(series = list(
  dataLabels =  list(format = "<b>{point.name}</b>:<br>{point.percentage:.1f} %<br>total: {point.total}")
        ))
```

**API Reference:**
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.series.dataLabels.format

**JS DEMO:**
http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/sry5mvzh/

Comment: Thanks @magdalena.  By default its display the count of each section in pie chart tooltip but ow do I display all the time total count of each section of pie chart. In above JS demo link it shows `total` which is overall total

Comment: Hi, sorry for the oversight. If you want to show the value of the slice, change this part of code: `%<br>total: {point.total}` to the following format `%<br>value: {point.y}` in both cases.